# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace ''are you missing an assembly reference ?"

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, resharper

I have a solution that worked fine until the last couple of days which contains around 15 projects that are DLLs or Webforms applications. I also use ReSharper which is another peculiarity related to this solution.

There are naturally projects referencing other ones within the solution and all but one compile independently and run OK except one Webforms app (A) that refers to namespaces within another Webforms app(B) DLL.

(A) has 7 exceptions when I try to debug this all along the lines of "the type or namespace name [MyClass] does not exist in the namespace '[(B) namespace]' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

All the projects target the same .net version 3.5 all target the same processor CPU architecture, I have cleaned the solution, recreated the reference to (B) from (A), can see the namespace in the object explorer when looking at it from (A)\bin so it's there... but still (A) at build has these errors above and for over a day now I cannot for the life of me work out why... can anyone help?

If I run the Webform app (B), it builds and runs without a problem...

The mention of ReSharper is due to it also not working with this solution anymore (but does work with others solutions), the behaviour of ReSharper with this solution is that I cannot type characters into VS anymore unless ReSharper is suspended. Also when searching for types the list does not filter down at all - so there is some sort of corruption there although I have cleared caches related to ReSharper.

Comment: The problem might be your virtual directory in IIS, it was not pointing to the correct folder, so the page couldn't find the DLLs

Comment: It's possible, I did find myself having to open VS2010 last week which suggested a virtual directory alteration to IISExpress (usually I use VS2013). Would it be the reference to the root of the site which currently does not run that you suggest may have the wrong path?

Comment: Yes, the IIS is currenctly pointing to the default folder now. Just redirect it to point to the current location of your file.

Comment: The only site from applicationhost.config with the port number matching the site I have an issue with does have it's root folder already pointing to the correct physical folder. Also When I try to debug the project, and it offers to run the last successful build this then produces a working site in IISExpress. So not sure it's the IIS which is the issue.

Comment: Then in References, under Solution Explorer, add the Namespace you want and reference it in the code.

Comment: The reference exists in solution explorer between (A) to (B), when I click on the (B) project reference to view it in object browser, the namespace exists in full with all it's classes, however when building (A) those "the type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace '' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" errors still persist... pointing to namespaces within the (B) project.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled ReSharper now that's got itself cool again with this project it seems, still have issues with build and references but looking further into dependencies on that one. 

Surprised that "Repair" for Resharper didnt do anything to improve it earlier today, but hopefully now it's alive within this solution the bigger issue will be resolved quicker!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your virtual directory in IIS, it was not pointing to the correct folder, so the page couldn't find the DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Brad McA, have you unblocked that namespace? In REFERENCES folder, right click on the particular reference, and see if there is an option "Unblock", If u can see it, kindly unblock it. Thanx

Comment: No option to Unblock that I can see

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be building now, reason for failure was a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json.dll which was built to target .net 4 (strange as this reference in (B) has been there for ages! why it would suddenly cause build issues).

Thanks to those who posted, have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0):

the dll reference were origionally built in framework 4.7.1. when trying to add the reference in lower framework project say 4.5.2. It gives such errors. try to update your project framework from 4.5 (lower version) to the version of your reference.